# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk ebextension

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I want to config the nginx config with the ebextension at Amazon Elastic Beanstalk,

The content of the conf as below:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom-nginx-proxy.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: "root"
        group: "root"
        content: |
            client_max_body_size 60M;

contatiner_commands:
    reload_nginx:
        command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

but always got the error about the content,

> nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "files:" in /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/nginx/conf.d/custom-nginx-proxy.conf:7

I put this file at

```
ROOT.war 
   |- ROOT/
        |- .ebextensions
               |- nginx
                    |- conf.d
                         |- custom-nginx-proxy.conf
        |- Others content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension should be placed at **.ebextensions/01-custom-nginx-proxy.config**. Also, the second block should start with `container_commands:`, not `contatiner_commands:`, and you don't need `sudo` as the deployment will already be running as root. If that doesn't help, try using two spaces per indent level. EB extensions are written in YAML, which is very sensitive to whitespace.

If you're still stuck, please post the contents of `/var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/nginx/conf.d/custom-nginx-proxy.conf` - the file that gets created after your deployment.

Comment: It should be 01-custom-nginx-proxy.conf or 01-custom-nginx-proxy.config ?

Comment: It should be .config - sorry for the typo.