# How to modify NGINX configuration on Deploying app Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to add some locations to nginx.conf so the environment URL points to app.php. I have modified the file using vi. Restarting NGINX it works. But I need this configuration to be load automatically when I use **eb deploy**.

I have read and tried:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

[Elasticbeanstalk configuring HTTPS on Single Instance of Python: null values are not allowed in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816885/elasticbeanstalk-configuring-https-on-single-instance-of-python-null-values-are)

[How to configure .ebextensions for nginx location directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335575/how-to-configure-ebextensions-for-nginx-location-directive)

[Amazon Elastic Beanstalk ebextension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153420/amazon-elastic-beanstalk-ebextension)

I have 
/.ebextensions/01_nginx.config

```
files:
"/etc/nginx/nginx.conf":
    mode: "0000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        My conf file
```

But that config is not working. I have tried changing "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": by "/etc/nginx/my_nginx.conf": and the file appeared! So I tried to replace default file by my custom file with:

```
container_commands:
    deleteConf:
        command: "sudo rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
    changeConf:
        command: "sudo cp /etc/nginx/my_nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

Placed below previous config inside 01_nginx.config. But commands are not working. nginx.conf is not being deleted or replaced by mine. What I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I have read that files in .ebextensions are evaluated alphabetically. I was wondering if maybe the copy command was being executed before the file exists. So I created a new file /.ebextensions/02_copy.config and moved there

```
container_commands:
    deleteConf:
        command: "sudo rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
    changeConf:
        command: "sudo cp /etc/nginx/my_nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

No luck with that

Comment: this is a very common problem and is poorly documented in elasticbean docs. for TLDR answer below by @guimauve , the hidden docs his here [amazon extended configuration for AMI 2](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending a whole day trying to modify **nginx.conf** on deployment, creating a custom **nginx.conf** directly in **/etc/nginx/** via a **.config** file in **.ebextensions**  didn't work for me as it would be systematically overwritten by the default one.

Same thing happened when I created the custom file in **/tmp** and wrote a **container_command** that would replace **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**.

You actually need to create a script that will be executed **after deployment**, after elastic beanstalk has written all your files.

### **If you are using an Amazon Linux 1 environment:**

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

To execute any script after deployment put the following code into your **.config** file at the root of **.ebextensions**

**01_write_custom_ng_conf.config**

1. Create a directory that will store your script.

```yaml
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

2. Create your modified **nginx.conf** file and place it in **/tmp**.

```yaml
files:
  "/tmp/custom_nginx.conf":
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       # your .conf file
```

3. Create a script that will replace the original **nginx.conf** by your custom one in **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post** created at step 1. This should be automatically executed after deployment.

```yaml
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/update_ng_conf.sh":
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content:
       #!/usr/bin/bash
       sudo mv /tmp/custom_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

### **If you are using an Amazon Linux 2 environment:**

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

Scripts are now executed from subfolders in **.platform** that you have to place at the root of your project, like so:

```sh
~/your-app/
|-- someFile.py
|-- Procfile
|-- readme.md
|-- .ebextensions/
|   |-- 01_write_custom_ng_conf.config        
`-- .platform/
    |-- hooks
        `-- postdeploy
            `-- 01_update_ng_conf.sh        # Executed post deployment
```

Create a **.config** file at the root of **.ebextensions**.

**01_write_custom_ng_conf.config**

Create your modified **nginx.conf** file and place it in **/tmp**.

```yaml
files:
  "/tmp/custom_nginx.conf":
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       # your .conf file
```

Create a small script in **.platform/hooks/postdeploy** and change permissions to **755**.

**01_update_ng_conf.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Replace the original nginx.conf by our custom one
sudo mv /tmp/custom_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Restart nginx to apply modifications
sudo service nginx restart
```

This worked perfectly fine for me on a **Amazon Linux 2 Python 3.7 environment**. Not sure about yours but this should be the same.

**Make sure that your **.config** files indentation is perfect as errors are not always detected by the parser and the code won't be executed.**

Comment: I gave up to do it like this. I need to deploy the app so I did it differently. But I didn't reach that hooks part of the docs when I was trying this. It worked for @nikhilswami so I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, this is NOT the way to do it on Amazon Linux 2. See AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) (section "Reverse proxy configuration") for the proper approach, which is to put your nginx config files in `.platform/nginx/` (in your source bundle).

Answer (score 2):

This answer applies to Linux 2.
I spent a whole day trying to solve this, mainly because I was trying to use the old approach, not realizing things have changed for Linux 2. I then found guimauve's answer, but it did not work for me. After reading the official AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html
I found that it is not necessary to create a script in .platform/hooks/deploy. You just need to create a nginx directory in .platform and put your updated nginx.conf in there. First attempt with this approach, the nginx.conf was successfully overwritten, but my call still timed out. I then added:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
```

in the server part of the nginx.conf and it worked! The call completed with no timeouts.

Comment: Just to clarify: This is Amazon Linux 2? And the additions are in nginx.conf?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing :)