# Why I need set SERVER_PORT:5000 in AWS Beanstalk to make Spring Boot app to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have simple CRUD spring boot app that I want to deploy to AWS via Beanstalk.

If I follow default steps and only choose custom VPC - app doesnt work.

If I doing the same and set SERVER_PORT: 5000 in env variables - app is working and I can use my API.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why I need set SERVER_PORT to 5000?
2. Why it is working now on port 80 and not 8080 as it is default port that it is running locally?

I solved the issue by adding env variable, but I want to know why I have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Spring Boot listens on port `8080`. However, by default the Elastic Beanstalk environment runs a reverse proxy server on port `80` and forwards traffic to your application on port `5000`. Thus, to have the traffic proxied correctly to your application, you either have to modify the reverse proxy to forward to port `8080`, or just set the `SERVER_PORT` environment variable (that Spring Boot automatically detects, and uses to configure what port it listens on) to port `5000`.

More details are documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How I can config reverse proxy so it can run on default 8080 port or any port I choose?

Comment: It's more difficult, and not recommended, but if you want to go that route it would look like the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299458/how-to-modify-nginx-configuration-on-deploying-app-elastic-beanstalk